# modify an existing file of powerpoint with java programming

Tags: java, powerpoint

am have problème with manipulation of powerpoint  format using java , i want to read a slid from an existing file(.pptx) witch containe one slid after that , generat a new file powerpoint containe a lot of copy of the first slid of the first file but we must add to it a paragraphe in middile , 
Thank you.

Comment: Is something like this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

[Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/slideshow/index.html) has support for both PPT file formats (97/HSLF and 2007 OOXML/XSLF). Examples can be found for the [former](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/hslf/examples/) and the [latter](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xslf/usermodel/) in the projects repository. In addition, they provide an [XSLF Cookbook](https://poi.apache.org/slideshow/xslf-cookbook.html) with several usecases.

Comment: thank you for this information , i found how to read an existing file pptx but i can't find how to copy past the first diapositive in a new file pptx

Comment: am training this code public class TextFormating {
   
   public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
    FileInputStream in=new FileInputStream("Exmples.pptx");
    XMLSlideShow ppt = new XMLSlideShow(in);
    
    List<XSLFSlide> listslide=ppt.getSlides();
    
    // and now how to add new text to listeslide.get(0) 
    // and write it in a new pptx file
    
   }
}